# Pandas. Check that rows are partly equals

Tags: python, pandas

I have table:

```
      tel size                       1              2      3     4
0    123    1                    Baby           Baby   None  None   
1    234    1                   Shave          Shave   None  None   
2    222    1                    Baby           Baby   None  None   
3    333    1                   Shave          Shave   None  None
```

I want to check if values in tables 1,2,3,4 ... are partly equal with 2 loops:

```
x = df_map.iloc[i,2:]
y = df_map.iloc[j,2:]
```

so df_map.iloc[0,2:] should be equal to df_map.iloc[2,2:], 
and df_map.iloc[1,2:], is equal to df_map.iloc[3,2:],

I tried:

```
x == y
```

and

```
y.eq(x)
```

but it returns error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If i use (x==y).all() or (x==y).any() it returns wrong result.

I need something like:

```
if x== y:
    counter += 1
```

Update:

problem was in None values. I used fillna('') and (x == y).all()

Comment: You can do `df.duplicated(subset=[1,2,3,4])` or `df.duplicated(subset=['1','2','3','4'])` but what is the actual desired output here as it's unclear

Comment: I don't know actual subset. It can be  [1,2,3,4] or [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] or other

Comment: Still unclear and vague, subset here refers to the columns to try to match on, I can only comment on what is posted, beyond that it becomes a fishing expedition

Comment: I want to check that df_map.iloc[0,2:] equal to df_map.iloc[2,2:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `fillna('')` because `None == None` is `False`
- use `numpy` broadcasting evaluate `==`
- `all(-1)` to make sure the whole row matches
- `np.fill_diagonal` because we don't need self matches
- `np.where` to find where the matches are

---

```
v = df.fillna('').values[:, 2:]

match = ((v[None, :] == v[:, None]).all(-1))

np.fill_diagonal(match, False)
i, j = np.where(match)

pd.Series(i, j)

2    0
3    1
0    2
1    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

THe type of pandas series(rows,columns) are numpy array,you can only get the results by column to column unless you loop again from the results which is also another array

```
import numpy as np 
x = df_map[i,2:]
y = df_map[j,2:]

np.equal(y.values,x.values)
```

Comment: returns ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: is y,x dataframe?in that case np.equal(y,x)

Comment: np.equal(y,x) returns ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().